# Error is not a function when call from component to model method

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting this error when I try to call from my component template to model method.

```
error in ./NewsListComponent class NewsListComponent - inline template:3:12 caused by: self.context.$implicit.toggleState
```

I get news from API and I can see the news on my component template.Then I'm trying to add an (click) event and call to toggleState() method from news. I'm just doing something following the hero tour.

Here I show some code

---

**news.model.ts**

```
export class News {
    constructor(
        id: number,
        title: string,
        news: string,
        path: string,
        date: Date,      
        public state = 'inactive',
    ) {}

    public toggleState()
    {
        this.state = (this.state === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active');
    }
}
```

**news.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Http, 
         Response, 
         Headers, 
         RequestOptions }   from '@angular/http';

import { Observable }       from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { News }             from './news.model';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {
    private url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_dev.php/news';

    constructor(private http:Http){}

    getNews(): Observable<News[]> {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers
        });
        return this.http
                    .get(this.url, options)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);                    
    }

    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        let errMsg: string;
        if (error instanceof Response) {
            const body = error.json() || '';
            const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
            errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
        } else {
            errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
        }
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json()
        return body || { };
    }   
}
```

**news-list.component.ts**

```
import { 
    Component, 
    OnInit, 
    Input,
    trigger,
    state,
    style,
    transition,
    animate }           from '@angular/core';

import { News }         from './news.model';
import { NewsService }  from './news.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'news-list',   
    template: `
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <h2>Noticias</h2>
            <div class="media" *ngFor="let news_ of news" 
                [@newsState]="news_.state"
                (click)="news_.toggleState()">
                <div class="media-right media-middle">
                    <a href="#">
                        IMG
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body media-middle">
                <h4 class="media-heading">{{news_.title}}</h4>
                <p>{{news_.news}}</p>
                <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    `,
    animations: [
        trigger('newsState', [
        state('inactive', style({
            backgroundColor: '#eee',
            transform: 'scale(1)'
        })),
        state('active',   style({
            backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
            transform: 'scale(1.1)'
        })),
        transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
        transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ],
})
export class NewsListComponent implements OnInit {
    error: string;
    @Input() news: News[];
    mode = 'Observable';
    constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {;
    }

    ngOnInit() {        
        this.newsService.getNews()
            .subscribe(
                (news: News[]) => this.news = news,
                error => this.error = <any>error
            );
    }
}
```

**news.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }         from '@angular/common';

import { NewsService }          from './news.service';
import { NewsListComponent }    from './news-list.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,  
    ],
    declarations: [
        NewsListComponent        
    ],
    providers: [
        NewsService
    ],
    exports: [
        NewsListComponent
    ],        
})

export class NewsModule {}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: Seems the `News[]` isn't really populated with News objects, if I create a news object explicitly I don't get the error.

---

**Problem solved by AJT_82 thanks!!**

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.newservice.getNews()
        .subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(n => {
                let newsObj: News = new News(n.id, n.title, n.news, n.path, n.date);
                this.news.push(newsObj);
            })
        });
}
```

Comment: How i can solve It using Observables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should clear up with just changing your subscription a bit, like so:

```
ngOnInit() { 
    this.newservice.getNews()
        .subscribe(data => {
            data.forEach(n => {
                let newsObj: News = new News(n.id, n.title, n.news, n.path, n.date);
                this.news.push(newsObj);
            })
        });
}
```

This way each news will be a instance of `News` and will have appropriate methods, such as your toggleState-method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You are welcome, glad I could help! if you'd kindly accept my answer by clicking the tick under the vote for this answer, I would be even happier :P